# Using spl_autoload_register

Tags: php, autoload, spl-autoload-register

Must I put the following lines in each PHP file I create to use autoloader? Or there is a solution to do it once, inside "index.php" of the application for example, and instantiate the classes in other files like usual?

```
function autoload($class) {

    require('/path/to/mylibrary/' . str_replace('_', '/', $class) . '.php');
}

spl_autoload_register('autoload');
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add these lines once. The rest of the request your autoload-function will be used to load the class-files. You should put this somewhere at the start of your php, for example in the index.php. But if you have multiple entry-points (for example http://www.example.com/index.php and http://www.example.com/page.php) all these files should have the `spl_autoload_register` (either via copy-paste but more preferable via an `include(..)`).

Comment: I have inside my application test folder the following files: "myapplication/index.php" and "myapplication/testfolder/testfile.php". If I don't put spl_autoload_register inside "testfile.php" too, I get an error "Class not found".

Comment: Exactly as I was saying. The autoloader should be registered somewhere during the request. That means that if you have a php-file that will be called directly from your browser it should register the autoloader (either direct or via an include). Files that won't be called directly but only are included doesn't need to register the autoloader.